# Prove that $\frac12\ln\left(x^2+1\right)=\frac{x^2}2+\ln x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I’m attempting to integrate the expression $\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2+1}$ with respect to $x$. I divided the numerator into the denominator and proceeded as: $\int\left(1+\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right)dx=\int dx + \frac12\int\frac{2x}{x^2+1}dx=x+\frac12\ln\left(x^2+1\right)+C$. My book confirms this is the correct answer.

However, it occurred to me that, rather than appealing to substitution, I could divide again, instead proceeding as follows:

$\int dx + \int x+\frac1xdx = x + \frac{x^2}{2}+\ln(x)+C$.

Assuming I did my math correctly, and I can’t see anything wrong with what I did, how are these two expressions equivalent to one another? Obviously the $x+C$ in both expressions will cancel out, but how do I show that $\frac12\ln\left(x^2+1\right)=\frac{x^2}2+\ln(x)$?

Comment: “Obviously the $x+C$ will cancel out” - danger danger danger

Comment: I don't understand how you divide in the second attempt $x+\frac{1}{x} \neq \frac{x}{x^2+1}$.

Comment: They're not generally equal.  How did you get $\int dx + \int x + \frac1x dx$?

Comment: $x+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x^2+1}{x}$ not  $\frac{x}{x^2+1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your division went upside down when you had $$\frac {x}{x^2+1} \overset{?}{=} x+1/x$$

You did the integration correct in $$\int dx + \int x+\frac1xdx = x + \frac{x^2}{2}+\ln(x)+C$$

but the mistake in dividing made your answer different from the correct one.